# Excel VBA-delete string and following line within a cell

Tags: string, excel, cell, vba

I need to delete certain strings (e.g. "SUBJECT:", there is a line break after this string), *and the entire following line, to and including the next line break*, from within multiple cells in Excel.

How can I write a macro for this?

I am guessing it would be

`Cells.Replace What:="Subject:" & Chr(10) & "[ANY TEXT]" & Chr(10), Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ ReplaceFormat:=False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in my case!

```
Selection.Replace What:="Subject:" & Chr(13) & "*" & Chr(13) & Chr(10), Replacement:="", Lookat:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find the starting point and ending point in the string using InStr:

> InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )

The starting point is found by searching for "Subject:":

```
startingPoint = InStr( cellValue, "Subject:" )
```

The End point is the second vbLf (line feed) character after that, so you want to start the second InStr at the starting point plus the length of the first search string (8) plus one:

```
endingPoint = Instr ( startingPoint + 8 + 1, cellValue, vbLf )
```

Then put it all together with the Mid function:

> Mid(text_string, start_position, Length)

The length will be equal to the ending position minus the starting position.